# Prevent component from being reset when moved in the DOM

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

See this [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljpjhv).

There are six rectangles you can drag-and-drop between the two drop zones.

One of them contains a component. If you click on the word *foo* (component property with value *foo*), it changes to *bar*. (see source)

Now, grab the rectangle containing the component and move to somewhere else. The component is reset, *bar* changes back to *foo*.

Any way to prevent this? I'd like the component to retain its state.

([issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16326))